# Multi Thread Communication (java)

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I'm writing an analysis of standard Maze Solving Algorithms and neural network based Maze Solving algorithms. I have created 7 classes (for now), one for each maze solving algorithm. In my main class, I initialize each of the algorithm objects, create a thread for each one, and make them solve a generated maze. Each of the algorithm's is basically comprised of one main loop and inner parts. At the end of each of the loops, I have a code segment that logs information needed for my analysis (time, number of steps, number of turns, etc.). After each of the algorithm threads has completed, I call a function which takes each of the algorithm objects and creates a png of the solved maze. Then I simply load this picture in a window.

This works fine, but for a live demonstration I would like the image to instead update for each loop cycle so that I could show the maze being solved in real time. For this to happen, I need each of the threads to stop in their loop at the part where they log the information until the main thread calls the function that creates the png. I'm not really sure how to make this communication happen, as all the algorithms complete a loop cycle at different times.

This is the code I have so far in my main function:

```
DepthFirst generator = new DepthFirst(30); // Generates the maze to be solved
byte[][] hi = generator.generate();

JFrame frame = new JFrame("DepthFirstTrial0"); // Creates the window to 
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // display the finished maze

MazeSolver mazes[] = new MazeSolver[7]; // Creates each of the algorithms
mazes[0] = new RandomMouse(hi); // They are all subclasses of MazeSolver
mazes[1] = new LeftHandFollower(hi);
mazes[2] = new RightHandFollower(hi);
mazes[3] = new Pledge(hi);
mazes[4] = new Tremaux(hi);
mazes[5] = new RecursiveBacktracker(hi);
mazes[6] = new DeadEndFiller(hi);

Thread mazeThreads[] = new Thread[7];
for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
mazeThreads[i] = new Thread(mazes[i]); // Puts each one in a threaad
}

for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
mazeThreads[i].start(); // Starts each thread
}

Thread.sleep(1000) // Waits at most one second for them to finish

MazeSolver.toPng(mazes, 0, "DepthFirst"); // Creates the png
frame.getContentPane().add(new MazeAlgorithmAnalyzer.loadImage()); // Loads into the window
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance!
Ashwin

Comment: Can't you just store all the moves and show them one by one after?  How long does it take for one step?  Also, timing your different threads with other solvers running gives you completely meaningless solving times.

Comment: The actual solving times themselves are not important. I am using the solving times simply for comparison among the algorithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a [CyclicBarrier](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html).

Inside each thread for each maze solver, after each step you just add the line

```
cyclicBarrier.await();
```

They will wait at that line until all other threads are at that point too and then they all start again together.

Comment: This works only if all solvers perform the same number of steps. If one of them finishes early, all the other solvers will remain blocked unless they're interrupted.

Comment: Agreed, you would need to modify the number of threads expected by the barrier as some of them finish.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works perfectly. As for finishing, the algorithms all finish at a different number of steps. Right now my workaround is for each algorithm to loop `cyclicBarrier.await();` after it finishes until all of the threads are finished. If anyone has an easier way of doing this, please let me know

Comment: @AshwinSekar if the thing you need is to just wait until other threads complete, consider [CountDownLatch](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) _"A synchronization aid that allows one or more threads to wait until a set of operations being performed in other threads completes..."_

Comment: @gnat You can't reset the counter on a CountDownLatch.  It might be possible to set up a new CountDownLatch when the previous one is done, but it might be tricky, if not impossible, to synchronize.

Comment: @toto2 I was thinking about using _latch_ after algorithm completion. That would require spawning some dummy thread to complete wait-steps at _barrier_. I haven't yet figured if that's better than waiting at barrier in algorithm.

Comment: @gnat OK.  I had thought a bit about that too.  You would need a thread for each extra `await`, so I thought it is probably better to just keep the original threads doing the `await`, like Ashwin did.  But there could be some better solution.

Comment: @toto2 _better solution_ than yours and Ashwin's in Java 6 seems unlikely. :) I'd say lack for a better solution was probably the cause to introduce [Phaser](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html) in Java 7. _"A reusable synchronization barrier, similar in functionality to CyclicBarrier and CountDownLatch but supporting more flexible usage..."_

Answer (score 2):

Use [`SwingWorker`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html). Have your maze solving algortihm invoke the `publish()` method each time an intermediate result is there. Some time thereafter, the `process()` method is called on the EDT where you can update the display.

Answer (score 0):

I must admit that I battled to understand your exact requirement but if you are trying to achieve basic inter-thread communication then you can probably accomplish this through wait(), notify() and notifyAll(). Here are two tutorials you can look at for these methods: [Here](http://www.roseindia.net/java/thread/InterthreadCommunication.shtml) and [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_thread_communication.htm).

Comment: You should __never__ use those unless you are designing custom threaded libraries.  And that's from the Bible: Java Concurrency in Practice by Goetz et al.